# Analog(?) Short Story 2 krakens(?) from different oceans fight. Smaller one helped by humans

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Pretty sure it was in an Analog. Mid 80s. World with two big oceans, similar to Atlantic and Pacific. Giant Kraken like creature, too big to travel to the other ocean now. Humanoids in sailing ships unite with the smaller sea monster from the other ocean and battle the 2nd larger monster.

More info: The Krakens (both) are intelligent. The smaller one was an offspring of the larger. The humanoids helped attack the other kraken in wooden sailing ships (I think): Flinging tar on fire? Perhaps the smaller kraken could send pieces(?) of itself to sense or scout the other ocean?  The smaller sea monster wins.

Comment: I believe this was one of a series of short stories that started publication in Analog in the 1970s.  I remember some plot details, but not author or titles.  I remember which sea monster is victorious, and how that happens.  I remember a priestess character that met an interesting end.  I also have vague memory that the natives resembled shrimp, but that could be due to the fact that I skipped lunch.

Comment: The Island of the Aunts by Eva Ibbotson features a small kraken and a large one. But that's pretty much the only similarity

Answer (score 7):

I believe I've found it.  There was a series of stories written by [Alison Tellure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alison_Tellure) and published in Analog between 1977 and 1984. The names of the giant sea creatures are FirstOne and Skysinger.  The priestess character I mentioned in my comment was named Green-Eyed She.

The stories are:

1. [“Lord of All It Surveys”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50262) - June, 1977
2. [“Skysinger”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?50263) - August, 1977
3. ["Green-Eyed Lady, Laughing Lady"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?49486) - March 1, 1982
4. [“Low Midnight”](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?48824) - May, 1984

They are well summarized here: [FirstOne and its Kin](https://jamesdavisnicoll.com/review/firstone-and-its-kin).

> “Lord of All It Surveys” • short story • (1977)
>
> This is the biography of a vast, inhuman intelligence. It begins with the abiogenic origin of life on a distant, unnamed world orbiting a blue-white star. Having stumbled across multicellularity, the entity expands to dominate its immediate environment. Once in possession of intelligence and curiosity, it uses the only tool available — itself — to spawn a bud to explore its world. This necessitates the invention of names — FirstOne for the original, First Child for the bud — and raises a question. Can FirstOne share a world with beings like itself or must they turn on each other?
>
> “Skysinger” • short story • (1977)
>
> FirstOne’s Descendant Skysinger makes a momentous discovery: the tiny land-dwelling creatures it has habitually gobbled are more than a delectable treat. They are surprisingly intelligent, despite being so much tinier than Skysinger’s kind. Scarcely has Skysinger had time to digest this information than it learns that ancient FirstOne, determined to have the world for its own, is methodically exterminating its offspring. FirstOne’s proxies are formidable, but FirstOne knows nothing of Skysinger’s discoveries nor of Skysinger’s ingenuity.
>
> Green-Eyed Lady, Laughing Lady • novelette • (1982)
>
> Green-Eyed She, also known as Wink, expects to serve God as a fisher, then (if she survives) as a Servant. To her astonishment, she is singled out for a very personal relationship with God, who is none other than Skysinger. Little of what God teaches Wink is welcome: God is no god, Wink’s people have somewhat misapprehended their relationship with Skysinger and worst of all, the great evil featured in their religion is very much real. Following Wink’s rebuke of the vast being for its treatment of her folk, a lengthy, fruitful relationship follows.
>
> At the end of the long partnership, Skysinger still eats the elderly Wink because hey, why waste food?
>
> “Low Midnight” • short story • (1984)
>
> Having prepared its land-dwelling allies for all-out war with FirstOne, Skysinger ventures out of the Lesser Sea to seek out its older, larger ancestor. Confrontation is delayed by the scale of the new ocean which Skysinger and its allies must explore. When confrontation does come, Skysinger discovers that it has seriously misunderstood the nature of the challenge.

“Low Midnight” was the last published work under the pen name Alison Tellure.  The author's true name is something of a mystery.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds a great deal like the end fight of The Blue World by Jack Vance.

The story takes place on a planet where a ship crashlands and people live on giant lily pads. The idea was that the hardest substance on the planet was their own bones. There is no land. There are large creatures known as Kragens which roam below in the ocean. One, the largest of all, is known as King Kragen. King Kragen is enormous and has been coming to feed and destroy for hundreds of years. Some of the humans worship it as a deity. When other Kragens come by, King Kragen will suddenly appear to destroy them in a fight reminiscent of Godzilla Vs Other Monster.

One day King Kragen did a great deal of damage, and a group of humans began to rebel, pointing out that King Kragen’s appetite had grown with his size and they could no longer afford to feed him and anyway he’s just a giant fish monster. The group are rejected as separatists and go to live on new lily pads.

There, the closest thing they have to a scientist builds essentially a giant magnifying glass which focuses the suns rays sufficient to burn away organic matter and leave small quantities of metal behind. In a world where bone had been the hardest substance, they rediscover copper and iron by bleeding themselves and burning off the organic portions.

They also rediscover basic electrochemistry and that the electricity can be conducted through spears fashioned from the different metals. They begin to hunt kragens which turn out to be excellent sources of iron. They find that they can control the Kragens by twisting nodules in the brain case.

Eventually they return home in a fleet, where King Kragen has set up permanent shop, and use their experience to destroy King Kragen. I believe they may have been riding controlled Kragens but they themselves fought and destroyed King Kragen.

Differences: it’s a book, not a short story. But it is a short book/novella. It may have been republished in the 80’s in a magazine. It was published as a book in 1980.

Comment: Hmmm... don’t think that’s it. But I’m sure I (or my dad) have that novel. Will check to see if I’ve crossed/mixed up memories.  98% sure it was Analog circa mid 80s.